# Dojo drag and drop for "list in list" (nested lists)

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo, drag-and-drop

i have a following HTML, and i use dojo drag and drop to sort attributes and to
drop them into another section. But how can i sort also sections? It doesnt work to me, what i have created:

```
<ul accept="section" data-dojo-type="dojo.dnd.Source" class="container dojoDndSource">

  <li id="section1" class="dojoDndItem" dndtype="section">
     <ul accept="attribut" data-dojo-type="dojo.dnd.Source" class="container dojoDndSource">
       <li dndtype="attribut" id="attribut1"></li>
       <li dndtype="attribut" id="attribut2"></li>
       <li dndtype="attribut" id="attribut3"></li>
     </ul>
  </li>

  <li id="section2" class="dojoDndItem" dndtype="section">
     <ul accept="attribut" data-dojo-type="dojo.dnd.Source" class="container dojoDndSource">
       <li dndtype="attribut" id="attribut1"></li>
       <li dndtype="attribut" id="attribut2"></li>
       <li dndtype="attribut" id="attribut3"></li>
     </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want to do: Move the inner list items amongst themselves in the same list, and also from list to list. You also want to move the two outer lists around. If so, try this:

```
<style>
.container {
  width: 50%;
}
</style>

<ul accept="section" data-dojo-type="dojo.dnd.Source" class="container dojoDndSource">
  <li id="section1" class="dojoDndItem" dndtype="section">
     <ul accept="attribut" data-dojo-type="dojo.dnd.Source" class="container dojoDndSource">
       <li class="dojoDndItem" dndtype="attribut" id="attribut1">one</li>
       <li class="dojoDndItem" dndtype="attribut" id="attribut2">two</li>
       <li class="dojoDndItem" dndtype="attribut" id="attribut3">three</li>
     </ul>
  </li>

  <li id="section2" class="dojoDndItem" dndtype="section">
     <ul accept="attribut" data-dojo-type="dojo.dnd.Source" class="container dojoDndSource">
       <li class="dojoDndItem" dndtype="attribut" id="attribut4">four</li>
       <li class="dojoDndItem" dndtype="attribut" id="attribut5">five</li>
       <li class="dojoDndItem" dndtype="attribut" id="attribut6">six</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The changes I made are:

- Fixed the duplicate IDs in the second list.
- Set the width of the 'container' class to less than 100%. This will give you a place to
  grab onto an entire list. List item
- Made your internal list items draggable by adding the class "dojoDndItem".